# How Do we read the message which is send to our bot by some user?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i have been designing my bot for 2-3 week. i have make the discord bot DM command through i can send message to anyone who is member of our server .. but how to read what they reply to that bot

Comment: Can you provide a code sample within the context you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the messages in DMs the same as you get normal messages, using the "message" event.
To see if the message was sent in DMs check if message.guild exists.
For example:

```
if (!message.guild) {return console.log(`New Message in DMs: ${message.content}`)}
```

According to your comment, "`i want to see that message in a specific channel and with their names`", you have to check the [Channel ID](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel). You can get the message author name by using [Message's](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) [Author](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) Property.

Here's an example:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client();

Client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false; // If the message is sent by a bot, we ignore it.
    if (message.channel.id == "661567766444376085") { // Checking if the message is sent in a certain channel.
        let Channel = message.client.channels.get("661567766444376085"); // Getting the channel object.
        console.log(`New message in #${Channel.name} from ${message.author.tag}: ${message.content}`);
    };
});

Client.login("TOKEN");
```

The output should be: `New message in #channel_name from Author#0000: Message Content!`.

Comment: Can you provide any information? What errors did you get?

Comment: sorry i have error in other code .. i try it is working fine

Comment: i want to see that message in a specific channel  and with their names

Comment: Alright. I'm going to edit my answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') { //read messages
    msg.reply('pong');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

click [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) for official docs.

Comment: not this bro i knw this .. i am asking that when my bot send dm to anyone . how to know what did he reply to that bot in dm ..

Comment: like if i send direct message to you through my bot .. and you reply to that bot how did i know what you reply ?

Answer (score 0):

Discord does not have the built-in ability to communicate with users as a dialogue. In order to organize such a communication, there are several options. You can use the `channel.fetchMessages` method, which will return all messages in the dialog as collection, but this is not very convenient. You can create a server and in this server create a channel for each user and send his messages there, and yours to him in dm. There are many implementation options, but all of them require serious study in order for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah!
Here is a code how the bot will send a message to a specific channel when someone `DM`s it

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const targetChannelID = 'YOUR_TARGET_CHANNEL_ID'; // Replace with your channel's ID where you want the message to be sent

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  // Check if the message is in a DM channel
  if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
    // Identify the user who sent the message
    const user = message.author;
    
    // Get the content of the user's message
    const userMessage = message.content;
    
    // Create an embed message
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`DM from ${user.tag}`)
      .setDescription(userMessage)
      .setColor('#0099ff'); // You can customize the color
    
    // Get the target channel where you want to send the embed
    const targetChannel = message.client.channels.cache.get(targetChannelID);
    
    // Send the embed to the target channel
    if (targetChannel) {
      targetChannel.send(embed);
    } else {
      console.error(`Target channel with ID ${targetChannelID} not found.`);
    }
  }
});

client.login('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'); // Replace it with your bot token
```